# User doesn't exists and no redirect to created tenant in django project

Tags: python, django, database, schema, multi-tenant

I have an application in django 1.11 where I use django-tenant-schemas (https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) to create an account for the user.
After creating a client and schema and domain_url, the user is not redirected to the address given in domain_url.

For example: I have domain_url = test.localhost in the form.
After creating an account, I am still on localhost instead of test.localhost.

When I go to test.localhost I get a login panel. I log in with the data I provided when creating, but I get a message to enter the correct data. I check the database using shell - the user exists.

The user is connected to the Company using ForeignKey.

accounts/view.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        company_form = CompanyForm(request.POST, prefix='company')
        user_form = SignUpForm(request.POST, prefix='user')

        if company_form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
            company_form.instance.name = company_form.cleaned_data['name']
            company_form.instance.domain_url = company_form.cleaned_data['name'] + '.localhost'
            company_form.instance.schema_name = company_form.cleaned_data['name']
            company = company_form.save()
            user_form.instance.company = company
            user = user_form.save()
            auth_login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post:post_list'))
    else:
        company_form = CompanyForm(prefix='company')
        user_form = SignUpForm(prefix='user')
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['company_form'] = company_form
    args['user_form'] = user_form
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', args)
```

Forms to create company and user:

```
class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Company', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': 'autofocus'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name',)


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('company', )
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

Answer (score 0):

re: User doesn't exist error - 
According to your signup view function, the user record is getting created in the public schema. But when you try to login to `test.localhost`, `test` schema is being used for all the DB queries. You can switch schemas like -

```
from tenant_schemas.utils import schema_context

with schema_context(customer.schema_name):
    # create your user here.
```